# When should someone use bit-field on a boolean value?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have been researching some code in c++ in unreal engine and I came across that they have on a header file 4 booleans declared as:

```cpp
bool bIsEvaluating : 1;
bool bIsStopping : 1;
bool bIsBeginningPlay : 1;
bool bCompleteOnPostEvaluation : 1;
```

and one boolean without bit-field:

```
bool bIsPlayingForward;
```

The 4 booleans with bit-field are set on constructor and changed or used on some functions. The boolean without the bitfield is set and used on some functions. My question is when would someone use bit-fields on booleans and why not use them always on booleans as they take only true or false values?

Comment: Reading bit fields is slightly more expensive then reading a single byte as the single bit needs to be extracted (masked and shifted) from the byte that is read.  Updating a bit field is similarity more expensive as the enclosing byte has to be read and the changed bit modified by masking before writing the updated value.  Also the layout of bitfields in implementation defined.

Comment: Only class members can be bitfields. And even then, its just a suggestion to the compiler. Additionally, it could be slower to read from or write to a bitfield.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Correct me if i'm wrong, so basically if i had 8 booleans as class members declared with bit-fields it would be mush faster to change these booleans instead of 1 byte of 8 booleans? Or the booleans with bit-fields benefit on storage only?

Comment: My guess is that the code evolved over time and different people had different ideas about how to represent a boolean and the current mess is what you are left with, for no real reason.

Comment: @Toulis When you use bit fields, a lot of implementations need to insert extra instructions to read or write that member. So it may be slower to use bit fields, and you need to consider if that is worth the reduction in class size.

Comment: The probably only way to know for sure is to benchmark the memory usage+performance of a program. Things that increase the likelyhood that using bitfields is a good idea are: 1. a large number of objects being used at a time. 2. the parts that are stored using bitfields being accessed together in many parts of the program. 3. The bit fields being rarely used at all. ...

Comment: On our embedded system, we use bit fields to compress the size of the data.  I have never used a `bool` bit field, we always use traditional `int` (although it should probably be *unsigned*).

Answer (score 0):

I use bit-fields for boolean values in Unreal Engine to save memory and improve performance. Using a bit-field can save memory if I have a large number of boolean variables that don't need a full byte each. Accessing a bit-field may also be faster than accessing a full byte, as it requires fewer memory accesses. This can be particularly useful in cases where I need to access the boolean value frequently. Additionally, using bit-fields can make it clearer that a particular boolean value is meant to be used in a particular way, which can improve the readability of my code. It's important to note, however, that bit-fields have some limitations and trade-offs, and I use them sparingly and only when the benefits outweigh the potential downsides.

In Unreal Engine, you should use bit-fields for boolean values when you have a specific reason to do so, such as to save memory or improve performance. If you don't have a specific reason to use a bit-field, it's generally better to use a regular boolean variable. You should also be mindful of the limitations and trade-offs of using bit-fields, and use them sparingly, only when the benefits outweigh the potential downsides.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think this answer is a bit misleading. First you describe upsides of bit-fields, then you just mention that "be aware of the downsides as well" (paraphrased), without even a hint of what those downsides are. Also, some of your upsides are disputable. The performance gain is questionable, as bitfields often require extra operations to read/write only the requested bits. You might even have a performance loss. And the "extra clarity", I would argue, is already provided by making the type `bool` - it's either true or false, whether it's 1 bit or 32 bits internally.

Comment: I referenced it in the context of "how i" (first person) approach it but also mentioning that there aren't a straight forward yes/no answer (hah boolean pun not intended).

The question is quite open for "it depends" tbh

Comment: To clarify: Bitfields may offer some performance and memory benefits in certain circumstances, but they can also have negative impacts on readability, complexity, portability, and performance. They can make code more difficult to read and understand, increase the complexity of the code, and be less portable across different systems (but assuming UE cross-compile portability may not be a factor).

Comment: @Scott So, outside of Unreal Engine (or inside whatever you prefer) you would use it on booleans that are barely ever accessed/writed to, in order to save memory?

Comment: @Toulis I came from an old C++ mindset where memory used to be limited and you had to squeeze as much as you could when you could. Since a standard boolean variable takes up a full byte (8 bits) of memory, using bit-fields allows storage of boolean values in a single byte. So.. i guess preference - "yes" but it always always ends on that weasel out answer of "it depends" (hehe sorry).  I am just attempting to answer the best i can without sounding too prescriptive? if that makes sense?